# how to show plt.plot 's xtick like ' 1990s ,2000s, 2010s' etc

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to show Detroit Pistons win rate record since 1948 by using plt.plot, and I want to turn x-axis's tickers into the interval like `['1940s'......'2010s']`

by the way, I find those data from Wikipedia. thanks

I've already used for loop to show the decade that each year belong
but I don't know how to show x axis's tickers as a decade interval.